# Multisim and DAC (summing op amp)

Tags: operational-amplifier, dac, multisim, summing

I am using multisim to simulate an inverting summing op amp (LM741CN). I calculate my expected Vout to be the following: -Vout = ((20/2.5)V1) + ((20/5)V2) + ((20/10)V3) + ((20/20)V4). According to my calculations, my Vout with binary input of 0001 should be -1. However, when I measure in Multisim, that is not what I get. Are my calculations incorrect or am I measuring incorrectly?

[image: circuit in multisim]

Comment: It will be helpful for other people that may attempt to help you if you updated your question with the updated circuits.

Answer (score 1):

The 741 can provide about 20mA, but you're asking for much more than that.  Bump all your resistor values by a factor of at least 20, if not 100.  Real circuits are not built with resistors that small.  Also, the outputs of the 741 are not rail to rail, and can only reach within a few volts of the rails.  Change the opportunity amp power supplies to +/- 15

Lastly, voltmeters need to be wired in parallel, not in series.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I bumped all resistor values up by 20 and then by 100 - my Vout was 0 constantly (after closing all switches).

Comment: @Markovnikov, see my edit

Comment: And make sure the switch is closed

Comment: I bumped all the resistors up quite a bit and changed the op amp power supplies to +/- 15 and I still get 0 volts as my Vout.

Comment: ![new circuit](http://i.imgur.com/5iQ6oLf.png)

Comment: @Markovnikov  obviously something is wrong.  Start putting in more voltmeters, even at the batteries, to make sure the simulation is running

Comment: ![circuit](http://i.imgur.com/7LR5lBD.png) It appears to be working, just not at Vout. I've got it set up just like as I should.

Comment: @Markovnikov, no...voltmeters go in parallel, not in series.  Wire it up between ground and vout

Comment: so something like this then? ![circuit](http://i.imgur.com/OBqnodV.png) ?

Comment: I don't know your tools.  Is that a voltmeter?  Does it give you the answer you expect?

Comment: It's a DMM and no it's not giving me the answer I expect. It displays -14.026 V constantly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong anymore.

Comment: @Markovnikov Now you need to ground the 5v supply